# iOS App crash AppleMetalGLRenderer gldReadFramebufferData

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am getting some crash reports on crashlytics. Which are related to AppleMetalGLRenderer. I couldn't find out anything related to AppleMetalGLRenderer in my code.

**Please see the below information.**
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXCBADACCESS KERNINVALIDADDRESS 0x0000000000000000
gldReadFramebufferData
keyboardarrowdown
Show all 29 threads

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0 libsystemplatform.dylib       0x1e567e674 platformmemmove + 132

1  AGXMetalA12                    0x1e67a442c (Missing)

2  AGXMetalA12                    0x1e67a4090 (Missing)

3  AppleMetalGLRenderer           0x1e5b97b2c gldReadFramebufferData

4  GLEngine                       0x1cf8742ec glReadPixelsExec

5 GLKit 0x1ce549740 -[GLKView snapshot] + 252

6 Mapbox 0x1076444b8 MGLStringFromMetricType + 36388

7 CoreFoundation 0x19e089764 CFNOTIFICATIONCENTERISCALLINGOUTTOANOBSERVER + 28

8 CoreFoundation 0x19e089718 __CFXRegistrationPostblockinvoke + 52

9  CoreFoundation                 0x19e088cd4 CFXRegistrationPost + 440

10 CoreFoundation 0x19e0886a0 CFXNotificationPost + 704

11 Foundation                     0x19f31c5f4 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64

12 UIKitCore                      0x1a0a3efb4 -[UIApplication deactivateForReason:notify:] + 1408

13 UIKitCore 0x1a00dad30 _101-[UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]blockinvoke2 + 984

14 UIKitCore 0x1a06254d4 UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 112

15 UIKitCore                      0x1a00da8c0 101-[UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]blockinvoke + 224

16 UIKitCore                      0x1a00da38c -[UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 484

17 UIKitCore                      0x1a00da6d0 -[UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 768

18 UIKitCore                      0x1a00d9f48 -[UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 340

19 UIKitCore 0x1a00e2078 _186-[UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]blockinvoke + 196

20 UIKitCore                      0x1a0537c28 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 892

21 UIKitCore                      0x1a063d810 UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 272

22 UIKitCore 0x1a00e1df0 -[UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 376

23 UIKitCore 0x19ff16eb0 _64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]blockinvoke + 776

24 UIKitCore                      0x19ff1586c -[UIScene emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 256

25 UIKitCore 0x19ff16ad8 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 248

26 UIKitCore 0x1a0560724 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] + 492

27 FrontBoardServices 0x1ad0dcb78 -[FBSScene updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 484

28 FrontBoardServices 0x1ad108194 _94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient queueupdateScene:withSettings:diff:transitionContext:completion:]blockinvoke2 + 152

29 FrontBoardServices 0x1ad0ead24 -[FBSWorkspace calloutQueueexecuteCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 240

30 FrontBoardServices 0x1ad1080c0 _94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient queueupdateScene:withSettings:diff:transitionContext:completion:]blockinvoke + 384

31 libdispatch.dylib              0x19dd28ac8 dispatchclientcallout + 20

32 libdispatch.dylib 0x19dd2c348 dispatchblockinvokedirect + 268

33 FrontBoardServices 0x1ad12e0e0 FBSSERIALQUEUEISCALLINGOUTTOABLOCK + 48

34 FrontBoardServices 0x1ad12dd88 -[FBSSerialQueue targetQueueperformNextIfPossible] + 448

35 FrontBoardServices 0x1ad12e2ac -[FBSSerialQueue performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 32

36 CoreFoundation                 0x19e0a781c CFRUNLOOPISCALLINGOUTTOASOURCE0PERFORMFUNCTION + 28

37 CoreFoundation                 0x19e0a7718 CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208

38 CoreFoundation                 0x19e0a6a28 CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268

39 CoreFoundation                 0x19e0a0d20 CFRunLoopRun + 824

40 CoreFoundation                 0x19e0a04bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600

41 GraphicsServices               0x1b4b25820 GSEventRunModal + 164

42 UIKitCore                      0x1a0a44734 -[UIApplication run] + 1072

43 UIKitCore 0x1a0a49e10 UIApplicationMain + 168

44 WJXT 0x102f45c38 main + 13 (main.m:13)

45 libdyld.dylib 0x19dd67e60 start + 4

**Please advise**

Comment: Did you get the solution or reason behind this crash?

Comment: No, I have not got a solution or reason behind this crash